# c# casting an object in a list of objects to a type returns a left hand signed must be a variable error

Tags: c#, list, object, types, casting

Wasn't sure how to go about with the title, but when I try to cast an object in a list, I get that error.

this is what I try:

```
(type)objectList[i] = typeValue;
```

I would expect this to work but it doesn't. Can I get some help on rewriting it?

Comment: You need to cast right of the equals sign.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` sign in C# is the assignment operator. It assigns the value on the right side of the equals sign to the variable on the left side.

You have your statement backwards

you can **assign** `objectList[i]` to the value of `typeValue` like this

```
objectList[i] = typeValue;
```

if `objectList` is an array of type `type` and `typeValue` is already a variable of type `type` then no cast is needed.

if `typeValue` is not of type `type` then you can cast it like this

```
(type)typeValue
```

Hopefully that clarifies the situation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completly sure what you mean, but if `objectList` is an array in `typeof(object)`, no cast is necessary. If you are trying to cast `typeValue`, then assign it, you would use:

```
objectList[i] = (type)typeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you cast an object to a different type, the return value is constant.  A value must be a variable in order to accept assignment.

That is, the correct way to cast and assign is like so:

```
FooInstance = (Foo)BarInstance; // this is a correct cast
```

The above code creates a constant value of type Foo from the cast, then assigns its value to FooInstance, which is a variable.

```
(Bar)FooInstance = BarInstance; // this will cause a compiler error
```

This code, if allowed to run, would attempt to assign the value of BarInstance to a constant value of type Bar, created by the cast.  Since you can't assign to constants, this is an error.

```
FooInstance = FooInstance2; // this works - no cast necessary
FooInstance = (Foo)FooInstance2; // this cast is unnecessary, but won't cause an error
(Foo)FooInstance = FooInstance2; // this will cause a compiler error
```

Even though they're of the same type, (Foo)FooInstance is constant, so it can't accept the value of FooInstance2.  FooInstance, on the other hand, is a variable, so it can accept any value of type Foo.

Comment: Having written this, I'm not certain whether the correct term for a return value is "constant" or "read-only".